# PHP preg_match any text in a url after a specific word already in the url

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using a preg_match to insert a joomla module into a template in any url that contains the word 'category'.

An example url is: xyz.com/page/category/

The code I have that works is:

```
if(preg_match('/category/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
echo '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="form" style="xhtml" />';
```

I have realised that I need to insert the module into pages that only appear in the url after 'category'.

eg: xyz.com/page/category/123-page-after-category

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
if(preg_match('/category/?.*',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

Comment: Looks to me like you.might as well use strpos

Comment: You can try with this regex `\/category\/?`

Comment: You want to include the module **ONLY** if there is something after `/category/` but not when URI ends with `category/`, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to only evaluate true if there are characters after `/category/`, then you need to make the quantifier "one or more" (`+`) instead of "zero or more" (`*`). In fact, you only need to check if there is a single character after `/category/`, so make "any character" non-optional.

This is a way:

```
if (preg_match('~/category/.~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
```

Keep in mind, regex patterns need "pattern delimiters" in php.  I've used tildes this time.  Your first pattern was being interpreted by the regex engine as `category`, and treating the slashes as delimiters -- this means you could have been matching "scategory-boardgame".

If you need case-insensitive matching, write `i` after the 2nd tilde. (Pattern modifier)

If you need to make sure that the characters that follow `/category/` are not querystring or anchor portions of the url, you can filter out `?` and `#`.

```
~/category/[^?#]~
```

Comment: If you are a Joomla developer, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.